# Images of movies I added to favorites do not appear on the screen

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I wrote the codes you have seen below. I would like to briefly explain the problem I encountered. After clicking on the movie's poster from the homepage, after going to the movie's detail page and pressing the add to favorites button, it adds it to the favorites. But when I go to my favorite movies page, there is no image there. How can I solve this problem.

My favorite_bloc.dart file:

```
class FavoriteBloc extends Bloc<FavoriteEvent, FavoriteState> {
  final SaveMovie saveMovie;
  final GetFavoriteMovies getFavoriteMovies;
  final DeleteFavoriteMovie deleteFavoriteMovie;
  final CheckIfFavoriteMovie checkIfFavoriteMovie;

  FavoriteBloc({
    required this.saveMovie,
    required this.getFavoriteMovies,
    required this.deleteFavoriteMovie,
    required this.checkIfFavoriteMovie,
  }) : super(FavoriteInitial()) {
    on<ToggleFavoriteMovieEvent>((event, emit) async {
      if (event.isFavorite) {
        await deleteFavoriteMovie(
          MovieParams(event.movieEntity.id),
        );
      } else {
        await saveMovie(event.movieEntity);
      }
      final response = await checkIfFavoriteMovie(
        MovieParams(event.movieEntity.id),
      );
      emit(response.fold(
        (l) => FavoriteMoviesError(),
        (r) => IsFavoriteMovie(r),
      ));
    });

    on<CheckIfFavoriteMovieEvent>((event, emit) async {
      final response = await checkIfFavoriteMovie(
        MovieParams(event.movieId),
      );
      emit(response.fold(
        (l) => FavoriteMoviesError(),
        (r) => IsFavoriteMovie(r),
      ));
    });

    on<LoadFavoriteMovieEvent>((event, emit) async* {
      yield* _fetchLoadFavoriteMovies();
    });
  }

  @override
  Stream<FavoriteState> mapEventToState(
    FavoriteEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is LoadFavoriteMovieEvent) {
      yield* _fetchLoadFavoriteMovies();
    } else if (event is DeleteFavoriteMovieEvent) {
      await deleteFavoriteMovie(
        MovieParams(event.movieId),
      );
      yield* _fetchLoadFavoriteMovies();
    }
  }

  Stream<FavoriteState> _fetchLoadFavoriteMovies() async* {
    final Either<AppError, List<MovieEntity>> response =
        await getFavoriteMovies(
      NoParams(),
    );

    yield response.fold(
      (l) => FavoriteMoviesError(),
      (r) => FavoriteMoviesLoaded(r),
    );
  }
}
```

my favorite_screen.dart file:

```
class FavoriteScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const FavoriteScreen({super.key});

  @override
  _FavoriteScreenState createState() => _FavoriteScreenState();
}

class _FavoriteScreenState extends State<FavoriteScreen> {
  late FavoriteBloc _favoriteBloc;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _favoriteBloc = getItInstance<FavoriteBloc>();
    _favoriteBloc.add(
      LoadFavoriteMovieEvent(),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _favoriteBloc.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: AppColor.transparentBackgroundColor,
        iconTheme: const IconThemeData(
          color: AppColor.whiteIconColor,
        ),
        title: Text(
          TranslationConstants.favoriteMovies.t(context),
          style: const TextStyle(
            color: AppColor.whiteTextColor,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: BlocProvider.value(
        value: _favoriteBloc,
        child: BlocBuilder<FavoriteBloc, FavoriteState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            if (state is FavoriteMoviesLoaded) {
              if (state.movies.isEmpty) {
                return Center(
                  child: Text(
                    TranslationConstants.noFavoriteMovie.t(context),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1,
                  ),
                );
              }
              return FavoriteMovieGridView(
                movies: state.movies,
              );
            }

            return const SizedBox.shrink();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Many thanks to everyone who has already helped.

Comment: Which version of bloc are you using?

Comment: flutter_bloc: ^8.1.3

Answer (score 0):

Your `FavoriteBloc` has in its constructor `on<Event>` statements. This was introduced in `bloc: 7.2.0`. The `on<Event>` statements function as mappings of an event to one or more states, therefore the method `mapEventToState` is not required anymore and should be removed.

The method `mapEventToState` was deprecated in version 7.2.0 of `bloc` and was removed in version 8.0.0. [migration guide from mapEventToState to on< Event >](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/migration?id=v720)

Comment: I don't get it. What do you mean? I'm new to flutter. I would be very happy if you show me by making changes on my codes.

Comment: You need to remove `mapEventToState` method. The method name is probably yellow in your editor and if you hover over it, it should state that the method is deprecated.

Comment: I did what you said, but the image did not appear on the screen again

Comment: You also need to fetch the movie again. `initState` is only called once. My suggestion is to store the loaded data in the bloc and when you add a movie as a favorite you modify this list. You would also need an event `RetrieveAllFavorites` or something similar, which returns this list.

Comment: If you do it by making changes on my codes, we will both save time. And you will not get tired. I would be very happy if you send it by making changes on my codes.